# pagination does not work with live data (react-admin)

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

**Hello everyone,**

I am using react-admin for admin panel. I am facing issue, the pagination does not work properly.

The pagination makes only for 10 records.
eg. if I have 100 records, there should be 10 pagination if every page has 10 records.

but it makes pagination for 10 records and shows all the records on the 1st-page. the plugin does not make pagination. Whether records are 100 or more than 100.

if i configure dataprovider with fake data, then it is working perfectly.

if anyone has idea about that please let me know solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are there 100 data on server . How are you getting response from the server?

Comment: yes, there are 100 records but all data shows on the 1st-page. the plugin does not make pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-admin` relies on `Content-Range` response header in order to build the pagination controls. Does your API return correct value like `Content-Range: posts 0-9/100`? Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment.